# finding colors in Image and redraw on second image(using numpy)

Tags: python, image, numpy, colors, find

I am trying to find specific colors(or more likely ranges of colors) in a picture and redraw the coordinates on a second picture for further investigation. Since I read a lot about how great numpy is, I started using that(I am pretty new with python and especially numpy).
So, I wrote something, that works good with one color, but has it's (performance-)problems with a lot of color and I am pretty sure, I can solve that, by using more functions that numpy provides. Basically, I want to kill the for-loops. That's my code(I have to add more ranges of colors later):

```
import PIL, numpy
from PIL import Image

def add_color_range(p_a_c, r,r1,g,g1,b,b1):
    for ir in range(r, r1+1):
        for ig in range(g, g1+1):
            for ib in range(b, b1+1):
                p_a_c.extend([[ir,ig,ib]])
    return p_a_c

for i in range(1):
    im = Image.open('%*s.bmp'% (1, i))
    n_test = numpy.asarray(im)
    ni_test = numpy.zeros([1050,1680,3],dtype=numpy.uint8)
    ni_test.fill(255)
    c=[]
    c=add_color_range(c,5,10,5,10,5,10)

    for ic in range(len(c)):
        ind=numpy.where(numpy.all(n_test==c[ic],  axis=-1))
        for ii in range(len(ind[0])):
            ni_test[ind[0][ii],ind[1][ii]]=[0,0,0]
    im_test = Image.fromarray(ni_test, 'RGB')
    im_test.save('test_%*s.bmp'% (1, i))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import PIL
import Image
import numpy as np

i = 0
im = Image.open('%*s.bmp' % (1, i)).convert('RGB')
n_test = np.asarray(im)
r, g, b = np.rollaxis(n_test, axis=-1)
ni_test = np.empty(n_test.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)
ni_test.fill(255)

mask = (r >= 5) & (r <= 10) & (g >= 5) & (g <= 10) & (b >= 5) & (b <= 10)
ni_test[mask] = 0
im_test = Image.fromarray(ni_test, '1')
im_test.save('test_%*s.bmp' % (1, i))
```

---

**Explanation:**

If I grok your code correctly, you are looking for points whose color fall within certain ranges. It will be convenient to define variables for each of the three RGB channels:

```
r, g, b = np.rollaxis(n_test, axis=-1)
```

If `n_test.shape` is `(w, h, 3)` then the shape of `r`, `g`, and `b` are each `(w, h)`. `n_test` is a 3D array, but `r`, g`,`b` are each 2D arrays.

Now instead of using `np.where` and selecting points associated with a particular color, we can eliminate all the `for-loops` by defining inequalities for the color ranges:

```
mask = (r >= 5) & (r <= 10) & (g >= 5) & (g <= 10) & (b >= 5) & (b <= 10)
```

Each parenthetical expression, such as `(r >= 5)` returns a 2D boolean array of the same shape as `r` (i.e. `(w, h)`). 
The `&` applies the logical-and operator element-wise. So `mask` is also a 2D boolean array. It is True wherever all those parenthetical expressions are true.

`ni_test[mask] = 0` indexes the 2D array `ni_test` with a 2D boolean array, `mask`. It assigns 0 to those location in `ni_test` where `mask` is True.

Comment: ok, thanks, that works amazing. I am waiting some time, if somebody else has another suggestion, but I think, that's pretty much it.

Comment: I got into another problem. I want a monochron picture as a result, not a RGB-picture. I tried some stuff, but it gives me strange result. What works so far, is to just add .convert('1') at Image.fromarray(ni_test, 'RGB'), but that means, that I create a RGB-picture and than convert it, instead of creating a monochron-picture in the first place.

Comment: I've modified the code to output a monochrome image. To do that, I gave `ni_test` the shape `n_test.shape[:2]`, and later convert it to a PIL image in mode `L`.

Comment: I tried the same, but I used mode '1'. it doesn't really make a difference.